# How to recognize if ESC is pressed?

Tags: java

I'm working in Java and have a method that reads input from keyboard with `input.next();`. I need to call another method if user presses ESC on keyboard. Is it possible to recognize ESC with `input.next();`?

Comment: What is the type of `input`?

Comment: You are using KeyEvent ?

Comment: please, show us a fragment of your code

Comment: `input` is the name of a variable.  We would need to know the class name to figure out if this is possible.  I'm assuming it's `Scanner`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

```
addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
...
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 27){   //this is the code for the escape key
    //call other method
    }
```

Let me know if I can walk you through in more detail.

Comment: I think the original poster is looking for something from System.in.

Comment: Better use KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE instead of 27

Answer (score 0):

I think I have some useful link which answers your question

http://www.thehelper.net/threads/detecting-the-escape-key-press-in-java.136974/